# Porch & Foyer on same circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, layout

Will it pass code if I put the Porch and Foyer (both receptacles and lights) on the same circuit?

[image]

Comment: It depends where you live. Code varies by region,

Comment: Regardless of code, I'm a fan of keeping lights and receptacles separated (both inside and out). For one, it avoids losing lights if you are working on a circuit or blow a breaker. For two, it avoids the voltage drop that causes lights to dim when you turn on a high-current device, such as a power tool, hair dryer, etc. It doesn't really add to the amont of wiring used because you can put more lights on a single circuit, and all outdoor receptacles on one if you want as well (and you'd only need a single GFCI for that).

Comment: Oh, while you're at it, now's a good time to put a receptacle up in the soffit, and perhaps another down to the right of the front entrance, so you can run christmas/holiday lights without extension cords running everywhere (if you do that or think a future owner would find it beneficial). You can put a switch (or better, electronic timer switch) inside to control them as well.

Comment: Unless there are local restrictions most entry areas are run on the same circuit and have been for years. Both inside and outside even if the outside entry is not covered.

Comment: I hear ya @gregmac, i kept lights and receptacles on separate circuits for all my rooms until i arrived to my Foyer and Porch. I figured, there would be no heavy duty devices running in this area. I could be wrong.(?)

But, EdBeal, is that what you meant? To put porch and foyer on same circuit and run lights as well as receptacles on it?

Comment: @true.lion with lighting circuits, wiring run lengths aren't a big deal if current is known to be considerably less than breaker capacity.  LED makes lighting loads very small these days.  You could tack those lights on the living room circuit.   I would not use the gallery circuit so if you have a trip, you can get spillover light from there.  A 20A breaker assures 12AWG cannot get hot enough to start a fire regardless of length.

Comment: Would it be a bad idea to combine the porch and garage? I'm just trying to thing of a way to not dedicate a breaker to such a small space (I imagine the porch has one electrical receptical and a few lights). Maybe put in a flag pole with a large light on the same breaker?

Comment: Exactly Scott. This is what's bothering me a bit, i really dont want a seperate breaker (and home-run) just for my Foyer and another for the Porch. There are no heavy devices that will run on these areas. The Porch receptacle might be chained with the rest of the exterior receptacles on the sides of the house.